# How to exclude files in a folder with pattern with robocopy?

Tags: windows, robocopy

I'd like to exclude all files matching `C:\dir1\*.ext` so I say:

```
robocopy C:\dir1 C:\dir2 /E /B /MIR /xf C:\dir1\*.ext
```

According to the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx) this should work:

```
/xf <FileName>[ ...]
```

> Excludes files that match the specified names or paths. Note that FileName can include wildcard characters (* and ?).

But it results in:

> ERROR : Invalid Parameter #16 : "xyz"

How can I exclude based on this pattern? Excluding by directory or by file name pattern is not specific enough.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you're missing a subfolder there, like in:

```
robocopy C:\dir1 C:\dir2 /E /B /MIR /xf C:\dir1\subdir\*.ext
```

Otherwise, this should work:

```
robocopy C:\dir1 C:\dir2 /E /B /MIR /xf *.ext
```

From my experience, `/xf` can use the wildcard just for names, and not for paths. I don't think it's possible that mix.

As a workaround, you may launch `robocopy` twice:

```
robocopy C:\dir1 C:\dir2 /E /B /MIR /xd C:\dir1\subdir\
robocopy C:\dir1\subdir C:\dir2\subdir /E /B /MIR /xf *.ext
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy:

> /xf <FileName>[ ...]   Excludes files that match the specified names or
>    paths. Note that FileName can include wildcard characters (* and ?).
>   /xd <Directory>[ ...]  Excludes directories that match the specified names and paths.

So this specifically means that wildcard can be used in the /xf flag but not in the /xd flag.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about [robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) syntax :

```
set _src="C:\dir1"
set _dst="C:\dir2"
set _option=/E /B /MIR
set _xf="C:\dir1\subdir\*.ext"

robocopy %_src% %_dst% %_option% %_xf%
```

Comment: The /XF switch is missing in your code. Even then, you are replicating the same OP code, wrapping it inside variables, so it won't work neither.